# Are Fortran FORMATs done during compile time or execution time?

Tags: fortran, runtime, compile-time

Part of the FORTRAN Syntax is FORMAT for example:

```
         WRITE(*,10)'this is a string', 'this is a second string', 'this is a third string'
10       FORMAT(1x,a10,1x,a10,1x,a20)
```

What I want to know is when the code is formatted, is it compile-time or execution-time? How could I test this? Checking the differences in assembly?

Comment: It's hard to answer in specific terms, so do you want to narrow this to a particular case where you care?  But you may want to consider the following program: `character(50) fmt; read '(A)', fmt; print fmt, 5; end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format strings are typically interpreted at runtime.  *After all those edits it is not that typical after all, see Steve's answer. The answer describes gfortran which might even be less typical, but is important and widespread.* Especially when the format string is a character variable (that can be anything), but also the FORMAT statement. You often get an error message for incorrect format only at runtime. For example:

```
          WRITE(*,10) x
 10       FORMAT(i0)
          END
```

gives

```
> ./a.out
At line 8 of file format3.f90 (unit = 6, file = 'stdout')
Fortran runtime error: Expected INTEGER for item 1 in formatted transfer, got REAL
(i0)
 ^
```

In your case:

```
 gfortran -O3 format3.f90 -fdump-tree-optimized
```

gives

```
  dt_parm.0.common.filename = &"format3.f90"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
  dt_parm.0.common.line = 1;
  dt_parm.0.format = &"(1x,a10,1x,a10,1x,a20)"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1};
  dt_parm.0.format_len = 22;
  dt_parm.0.common.flags = 4096;
  dt_parm.0.common.unit = 6;
  _gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.0);
  _gfortran_transfer_character_write (&dt_parm.0, &"this is a string"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 16);
  _gfortran_transfer_character_write (&dt_parm.0, &"this is a second string"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 23);
  _gfortran_transfer_character_write (&dt_parm.0, &"this is a third string"[1]{lb: 1 sz: 1}, 22);
  _gfortran_st_write_done (&dt_parm.0);
  dt_parm.0 ={v} {CLOBBER};
```

The `_gfortran_st_write (&dt_parm.0);` sets the writing mode and that includes the format string.

You can notice that the format is stored in a character variable and could be interpreted at runtime if necessary, but it is not actually used in the code generated by the compiler. It is potentially used inside `_gfortran_transfer_character_write` that are part of the libgfortran runtime library.

The above is for gfortran. One can imagine a lot can be actually optimized away and compiled, but I am not aware that compilers do that.

If you are curious, the gfortran format interpretting code is in  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/trunk/libgfortran/io/format.c

Comment: I'm always curious, that's what makes people geniuses. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The compilers I have worked on have always translated the format to an internal representation at compile time, other than formats stored in a character variable. The run-time system still has to have the ability to "compile" formats at run-time, but the compiler can check for errors. The actual formatting of the output always happens at run-time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying to write a dissertation on programming efficiency, understanding micro differences in run-time can help me reach an optimal understanding of efficient programming.

Comment: I hope you won't be offended if I suggest you're approaching the topic from the wrong end. Focusing on "micro-differences" is rarely productive, and is a subject best left to the compiler. Significant performance improvements are found by looking at 1) algorithms, 2) parallelism, 3) use of optimized libraries (for example, Intel MKL) instead of rolling your own. Especially when you get into I/O, very little is under your control. Sure, formatted I/O with formats in variables is less efficient than compile-time formats, unformatted is faster still. It is rare that this matters.

Comment: Sorry, for the late comment. Thank you for your input, while I see there being a "rarely productive" attribute to it. Beyond the big stuff, like you mentioned, there should be a fine tuning aspect to programming efficiency. This is why I wanted to focus my time in perfecting the things that can be perfected to the extent of a hardware wall. What I'm hoping to achieve is multi-CPU bus parallelism with a graphical output, which is why I'm working with FORTRAN. I feel there's mountains of untouched potential in this area.